# SSRS report with chart appears pixelated when exported to pdf

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS report with chart appears pixelated when exported to pdf. The same chart when exported to excel appears to be good. Is this a known issue with pdf? do we have any workaround to display the chart properly in pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your chart in a **Rectangle**.

The issue may be due to the chart being rendered into an image and then the image being resized in the PDF export leading to the blurry/pixelated look.

Comment: I have my chart inside Rectangle and i still have this issue.